# How to compose a table based on two other Tables?

Tags: sql

Given the tables and the query:

```
CREATE TABLE #samples1 (SampleID int, ValueA float)
CREATE TABLE #samples2 (SampleID int, ValueB float)

INSERT INTO #samples1 VALUES (2, 2.0), (3, 3.0), (4, 4.0)
INSERT INTO #samples2 VALUES (1, 1.5), (2, 2.5), (3, 3.5)

SELECT * FROM #samples1 FULL JOIN #samples2 ON #samples1.SampleID=#samples2.SampleID --??

DROP TABLE #samples1
DROP TABLE #samples2
```

How can I merge both of them? The result of this query is not exactly what I need. I want to merge both tables and keep samples that have values on both ValueA and ValueB but also the ones on just either of them. The result would contain samples IDs 1,2,3 and 4.

Comment: Are you thinking of something like UNION?

Comment: No, because UNION would put ValueA and ValueB into the same column

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SampleID, ValueA
    FROM #samples1
UNION ALL
select SampleID, ValueB
    FROM #samples2
```

Comment: Not a UNION ALL, since the result must contain a column ValueA and a column ValueB

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2008, you could possibly use the [merge statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)  to merge the one table into another.

This statement provides cases to help you handle the situation above like both tables have an ID 2.  So you could do something like:

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    <ignore the result>
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    <insert new record into table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.SampleID, ValueA, ValueB FROM #samples1 A
  LEFT JOIN #samples2 B ON A.SampleID=B.SampleID
UNION
SELECT A.SampleID, ValueA, ValueB FROM #samples2 A
  LEFT JOIN #samples1 B ON A.SampleID=B.SampleID
```

Verified in [HERE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/121556/)